# Cross browser automated testing - not able to retrievie element from document using sourceIndex

Tags: web, cross-browser, automated-tests

We have some dll written for retrieving/identifying an element from a document. The dll is written in C++ and was written very specific to IE. The logic to retrieve use the sourceIndex concept. Now we want to increase support for FireFox and Chrome, but unfortunately sourceIndex is not supported for these browsers. So do we have any other way using which we can retireve which is similar to sourceIndex for FF and Chrome. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have several great options for good cross-browser testing. You can look to [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), a very powerful, widely used driver. There are implementations in all major languages so you're covered for Ruby, Java, Python, and .NET.

I'd also like to recommend [Telerik's Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools) which is a commercial tool that does a great job with all aspects of web automated testing -- cross-browser support is particularly good. Please note that I'm biased since I'm their evangelist for the tool. :)

Comment: Thanks Jim , but actually we already have the code ready for IE and we just want to enhance for FF and Chrome. Please let me know if you can help me in replacing sourceIndex to anything common across all the browsers.